# Retag /proc filesystem questions tagged [proc] to [procfs]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

According to the [proc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proc) tag description, it's about `Proc` in Ruby, which seems to be a type of closure. This `Proc` has nothing to do with the `/proc` filesystem. There are [several questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3A%22%2Fproc%22+%5Bproc%5D+is%3Aquestion) tagged [proc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proc) but asking about `/proc` instead of the Ruby `Proc`.

I think these questions should be tagged [procfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/procfs), as this tag is clearly about `/proc` filesystem, not Ruby's `Proc`.

Regarding the tag naming pattern,
[btrfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/btrfs) [ntfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ntfs) [zfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zfs) [efs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/efs) [apfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apfs) [moosefs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moosefs) [refs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refs) [amazon-efs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-efs) [mogilefs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mogilefs) have fs at the end, [ext2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ext2) [ext3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ext3) [ext4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ext4) [fat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fat) [exfat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exfat) [fat16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fat16) [fat32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fat32) don't have `fs` in the name. I don't see any tags following the pattern `*-fs` on the [tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=name). There is also [adfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adfs) but that isn't a filesystem but rather a authentication service.

EDIT: here's [another query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bproc%5D+filesystem+-ruby+is%3Aquestion) that has 14 questions tagged with [proc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proc) and mentioning "filesystem" but not mentioning Ruby. These should probably also be tagged [procfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/procfs).

Comment: Are there any other "filesystem" related tags that have a certain format? (Eg. `*-fs` vs just `fs` at the end) If there's a precedent already, we should try to follow it.

Comment: @zcoop98 almost all common filesystem use fs as a suffix, notable exceptions: fat, ext*.

Comment: Personally, I see no point in using proc tags. Most of the time a programmer don't want to read/write from prog but use the ABI/API provided by libc, which would do so.

Comment: Wikipedia has it as `procfs`, too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs (no hyphen)

Comment: some other exceptions: UDF, Reiser4, ISO 9660

Comment: @Braiam Only as a last desperate resort. Otherwise, I'm quite happy living in Unix-land where everything is a file and I can use `find` and `grep` to do my fiddling.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- if you are using python, go, c, etc. why would you use find/grep?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For 12 questions (or 12 questions left when I looked), this doesn't really warrant anything more than a bit of editing by an empowered user.

I'm an empowered user; I've finished the task, including editing the content of the questions for standard fixups.

<sup>*(Aside: I wish Grammarly could distinguish between edits I make to other people's text and text I write de novo — my accuracy rating is horrid because of the fixup work I do.)*</sup>

The query in the question no longer yields any results.

Comment: should you edit op post to say status-completed then?

Comment: AFAIK, I can't do that — that's a moderator action, isn't it, @DanielWiddis?  I just tried and it gives me an error: _'status-completed' can only be used by moderators._

Comment: I didn't know, but now I do!

Answer (score -3):

1. If the same names are used for essentially different things. The ruby proc has nothing to do with the procfs of the unixes.
2. I think the ruby [proc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proc) should be retagged as [ruby-proc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-proc).
3. btrfs is never used as "btr", but ext4 is almost never used as "ext4fs". Thus, I think, in the case of filesystems, we should consider the "fs" suffix as a part of the name of the filesystem. Thus it should remain as it is.